# не находит поле по xpath, class и id / selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

teleph = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="phone"]')
teleph.send_keys("9211234567")
```

не ищет `xpath` также пробовал `class` и `id` везде ошибка, хочу чтобы заполнило поле ввода, но выводит такую ошибку

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element:  Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone"]"}

```
HTML код
<input id="phone" name="Телефон" aria-label="Номер телефона" autocomplete="tel" placeholder="" class="input__input" type="tel">
```

Comment: укажите ресурс и ошибку

Comment: вот ошибка selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="phone"]"} url = https://www.lamoda.ru/p/rtlaan778401/shoes-adidasoriginals-kedy/ нажимайте добавить в корзину, выбераешь любой размер, дальше перейти в корзину и там будет номер телефона,вот это поле ввода надо заполнить как раз где и была ошибка.